# SQL Server--piecemeal restore of filegroups from complete backup in Simple Recovery Mode

Tags: sql-server, database-restore, filegroup

We have a large database in MS SQL in which one of the tables is partitioned by a date column.  The Primary key index is also partitioned using the same partition function.  The database is kept in Simple Recovery model, since data is added to it in batches every 3 months.

DBCC checkfilegroup found consistency errors, so we needed to bring back just one filegroup from a complete backup.

Restore did not allow me to run a restore of a filegroup in Simple Mode, so I changed to full recovery mode, then ran the following, with no errors.

restore database aricases filegroup='2003'
from disk=N'backupfile-name.bak'
with recovery

I expected the "with recovery" clause to bring this back to working order, but the process ended with a note saying

The roll forward start point is now at log sequence number (LSN) 511972000001350200037. Additional roll forward past LSN 549061000001370900001 is required to complete the restore sequence.

When I query the database table that includes this filegroup I get a message saying that the primary key cannot be accessed because one of the partitions for the table cannot be access because it is offline, restoring, or defunct.

Why didn't "with recovery" clause leave this filegroup fully restored.  Now what?
The entire database is very large (1.5TB).  I can't backup the log file, because I'd first need to create a backup in full model mode.  The filegroup itself is only 300gb.

I can do the restore again-- but would like to know the correct way of performing this.
Is there a way of staying in complete recovery mode and performing a piecemeal filegroup backup from a complete database backup?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.  Bottom line is that Simple Recovery Model is very limited.  You must restore ALL read/write filegroups together from the same backup.  Individual read/only filegroups CAN be restored separately, as long as they became read/only (no more changes) BEFORE the last backup of the  read/write filegroups.

Bottom line-- only Full or Bulk-Logged models let you restore single read/write filegroups.
Bulk-Logged model is what a datawarehouse with batch loading should be using, not Simple Model.  My error in design.

see from Microsoft

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191253.aspx

then look at piecemeal restores for Simple Model
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190984%28v=sql.100%29.aspx
very limited